# Parse server payload with few keys absent

Tags: python, json, xml, metadata

I have a rather basic bit of code. Basically what it does is sends an API request to a locally hosted Server and returns a JSON string. I'm taking that string and cracking it apart. Then I take what I need from it, make a Dictionary, and export it as an XML file with an nfo extension.

The issue is sometimes there are missing bits to the source data. Season is missing fairly frequently for example. It breaks the Data Mapping. I need a way to handle that. For somethings I may want to exclude the data and for others I need a sane default value.

```
#!/bin/env python

import os
import requests
import re
import json
import dicttoxml
import xml.dom.minidom
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
# Grab Shoko Auth Key

apiheaders = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

apidata = '{"user": "Default", "pass": "", "device": "CLI"}'

r = requests.post('http://192.168.254.100:8111/api/auth',
                  headers=apiheaders, data=apidata)
key = json.loads(r.text)['apikey']

# Grabbing Episode Data
EpisodeHeaders = {
    'accept': 'text/plain',
    'apikey': key
}

EpisodeParams = (
    ('filename',
     "FILE HERE"),
    ('pic', '1'),

)

fileinfo = requests.get(
    'http://192.168.254.100:8111/api/ep/getbyfilename', headers=EpisodeHeaders, params=EpisodeParams)

# Mapping Data from Shoko to Jellyfin NFO
string = json.loads(fileinfo.text)
print(string)
eplot = json.loads(fileinfo.text)['summary']
etitle = json.loads(fileinfo.text)['name']
eyear = json.loads(fileinfo.text)['year']
episode = json.loads(fileinfo.text)['epnumber']
season = json.loads(fileinfo.text)['season']
aid = json.loads(fileinfo.text)['aid']
seasonnum = season.split('x')

# Create Dictionary From Mapped Data

show = {
    "plot": eplot,
    "title": etitle,
    "year": eyear,
    "episode": episode,
    "season": seasonnum[0],
}
```

Here is some example output when the code crashes

```
{'type': 'ep', 'eptype': 'Credits', 'epnumber': 1, 'aid': 10713, 'eid': 167848, 
'id': 95272, 'name': 'Opening', 'summary': 'Episode Overview not Available', 
'year': '2014', 'air': '2014-11-23', 'rating': '10.00', 'votes': '1', 
'art': {'fanart': [{'url': '/api/v2/image/support/plex_404.png'}], 
'thumb': [{'url': '/api/v2/image/support/plex_404.png'}]}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fletcher/Documents/Shoko-Jellyfin-NFO/Xml3.py", line 48, in <module>
    season = json.loads(fileinfo.text)['season']
KeyError: 'season'
```

The solution based on what Mahori suggested. Worked perfectly.

```
eplot = json.loads(fileinfo.text).get('summary', None)
etitle = json.loads(fileinfo.text).get('name', None)
eyear = json.loads(fileinfo.text).get('year', None)
episode = json.loads(fileinfo.text).get('epnumber', None)
season = json.loads(fileinfo.text).get('season', '1x1')
aid = json.loads(fileinfo.text).get('aid', None)
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to narrow your code and question down? Is there any error you're getting? Considered a defaultdict ?

Comment: my apologies. the issue is with the Data Mapping. when it tries to pull a value not there it just crashes. I'll provide an example of the error.

Comment: You could store the dictionary in a variable, then use either `if ‘season’ in mydict:` or `mydict.getdefault(‘season’,’no soeason’)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly common scenario with web development, where you cannot always assume other party will send all keys.

The standard way to get around this is by using `get` instead of named fetch.

```
season = json.loads(fileinfo.text).get('season', None)
#you can change None to any default value here
```

Comment: Oh that's amazing. That's exactly what I needed for season. And I can just assign a Null Value for anything else?

Comment: Well, it depends. Ofcourse you can assign anything, not just None. But the actual values will come from your business logic.  eg. Sometimes you may want to return empty list, sometimes a default integer value etc.

Comment: In this case  "None" will probably work fine since the NFO importer doesn't expect every value to be there. I'm just trying to pull all the Data I can to ease the data importing later down the line. For season I assumed a Value of "1x1" because of how I had to parse the inital raw data